# eclipse custom widget like "Outline" or "help"

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How to create and  open an custom UI integrated with browser and open in right side panel like "Outline" or "help" when an event like function key is pressed. Note that would like not display existing Help system. Would like to create similar UI widget like Outline or help and insert browser in it.

[image]

Comment: This is far too broad for a Stack Overflow question

Comment: Look at how Eclipse or other open source plug-ins are doing it.